# Insert picture comment with C# Ok while copy content with comments fail

Tags: c#, excel, comments

I'm working on excel using C#, but I face some issues while insert picture comments into excel. 
Here is my code:

```
public void InstertPictureComment(Excel.Range myrange, string picturepath)
{
    myrange.ClearComment();
    myrange.AddComment();
    myrange.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture(picturepath);
    myrange.Comment.Shape.Width=400;
    myrange.Comment.Shapes.Height=300;
}
```

The above code works well and I can succesfully insert picture comments. 
However, issues show up.
     Copy the contents (with the picture comments I have just inserted) to other excel worksheet
      ==>save excel, and close excel app 
      ==> reopen excel, and  a messagebox telling "Excel found unreadable content in xxxxx"

What's wrong with my code? Or it's an excel issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the code so that it compiles

```
public void InstertPictureComment(Excel.Range myrange, string picturepath)
{
    myrange.Cells.ClearComments();
    myrange.AddComment();
    myrange.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture(picturepath);
    myrange.Comment.Shape.Width = 400;
    myrange.Comment.Shape.Height = 300;
}
```

Part of the problem is with Excel. With your code, you are probably creating a new application instance of Excel. Excel is unable to copy objects across the application instances.

If you open another workbook in the same application instance, the objects will get copied. The only way to copy data across application instances is using Paste Special functionality.

You should fetch the existing Excel application instance. If it is not there, then you may create it.

```
private Excel.Application GetExcelInstance()
{
    Excel.Application instance = null;
    try
    {
        instance = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
    {
        instance = new Excel.Application();
        appCreatedExcelInstance = true;
    }

    return instance;
}
```

You may use the appCreatedExcelInstance flag to decide whether or not to quit the instance during cleanup.