# How to insert comment with picture into excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, comments

As what I described in title, how to insert a picture as a comment into Excel using C#? 
Please offer a sample code or some reference documents. 
Following is my code:

```
using Excel=MicroSoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
publice void ExcelEdit(string Path)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.WorkBook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.WorkSheet xlWorkSheet;
    Excel.Range myRange;
    xlApp=new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    xlWorkBook=xlApp.WorkBooks.Open(Path, misValue, misValue,misValue, misValue,misValue, misValue,misValue, misValue,misValue, misValue,misValue, misValue,misValue, misValue)
    xlApp.Visable=True;
    xlWorkSheet=(Excel.WorkSheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

    myRange=WorkSheet.Range[WorkSheet.Cells[1,1],WorkSheet.Cells[1,1]);
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1]=InstertPictureComment(myRange,Path);

    myRange=WorkSheet.Range[WorkSheet.Cells[1,2],WorkSheet.Cells[1,2]);
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1]=InstertPictureComment(myRange, Path);

}
public void InstertPictureComment(Excel.Range myrange, string picturepath)
{
     myrange.ClearComment();
     myrange.AddComment();
     myrange.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture(picturepath);
     myrange.Comment.Shape.Width=400;
     myrange.Comment.Shapes.Height=300;
}
```

I can successfully insert picture comments into excel. The problem is that: when I copy  and paste the cells which I have just inserted comments, save the excel, and close it. The next time When I open the excel, messagebox shows "unreadable content in xxx has found. "

What to do with my code!!

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be repeat of [Insert picture comment with C# Ok while copy content with comments fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730725/insert-picture-comment-with-c-sharp-ok-while-copy-content-with-comments-fail/26777641#26777641)

I just now posted an answer there. Copying the same answer here.

I have corrected the code so that it compiles

```
public void InstertPictureComment(Excel.Range myrange, string picturepath)
{
    myrange.Cells.ClearComments();
    myrange.AddComment();
    myrange.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture(picturepath);
    myrange.Comment.Shape.Width = 400;
    myrange.Comment.Shape.Height = 300;
}
```

Part of the problem is with Excel. With your code, you are probably creating a new application instance of Excel. Excel is unable to copy objects across the application instances.

If you open another workbook in the same application instance, the objects will get copied. The only way to copy data across application instances is using Paste Special functionality.

You should fetch the existing Excel application instance. If it is not there, then you may create it.

```
private Excel.Application GetExcelInstance()
{
    Excel.Application instance = null;
    try
    {
        instance = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
    {
        instance = new Excel.Application();
        appCreatedExcelInstance = true;
    }

    return instance;
}
```

You may use the appCreatedExcelInstance flag to decide whether or not to quit the instance during cleanup.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly guidness. But I don't think it's the root cause. When I insert only 1 picture comment, it's Ok. When I insert several picture comments each contains a different picture, the problems occurs. What's more, copy of the picture comment inserted at first is Ok, while the others are not. Do you have any idea on this?